# jsTree Object has no method addBack

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

This is my instantiation code for the jsTree.

```
$("#folder_tree").jstree({
    "themes" : {
        "theme" : "default",
        "dots" : true,
        "icons" : true
    },
    "json_data" : {
        "ajax" : {
            "url" : "/portal/folders",
            "data" : function(n) {
                if ($(n[0]).find("a").attr("id")) {
                    console.log($(n[0]).find("a").attr("id").split('_')[1]);
                    return {
                        "id" : $(n[0]).find("a").attr("id").split('_')[1]
                    };
                }
                return { "id" : "0" };
            }
        }
    },
    "plugins" : [ "themes", "json_data", "ui", "contextmenu", "dnd", "search", "crrm" ]
}).bind("select_node.jstree", function(e,data) {
    console.log(data.rslt.obj.context.id);
});
```

It loads the data correctly on the first load (the 0 case), but then when I click to expand any of the folders, it is giving me the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'addBack'
```

Even though the correct id of the expanded node is being logged to the console and the ajax request is being made to the server correctly. Notice also that I have to use a fairly horrific kludge to find the id of the element due to the fact that the documented code produces nothing but errors for me (and I am using the same version of jsTree as the documentation) when trying to access `n.attr("id")`. Plus, under `bind("select_node"...` I have to use a non-documented function to find the id again. After hours of troubleshooting, I'm still completely baffled, but something is clearly not operating correctly.

Comment: Are you using jQuery 1.8 or later? `addBack` wasn't added until then.

Comment: I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Make sure you are using jQuery 1.8 or later. `addBack` wasn't added until then.

Comment: This problem had ate-up my one hour. Thanks for your solution.