# Adding the addBack function to jQuery version 1.7.2

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am currently using jQuery 1.7.2. I have added a jQuery.UI dropdown element to my application but I am getting an error when I try to close it.

```
Object has no method addBack
```

I found the answer here: [jsTree Object has no method addBack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15057620/jstree-object-has-no-method-addback)

Turns out the addBack method wasnt added until v1.8. I'm not able to update to 1.8 for a few reasons, so is it possible to add the addBack function to v1.7.2?

I think this is the correct addBack function:

```
 addBack: function( selector ) {
                return this.add( selector == null ?
                 this.prevObject : this.prevObject.filter(selector)
           );
   }
```

Any advice or assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not upgrading your jquery version? Or why not just use andSelf() method?

Comment: Our entire system has to be updated and that will take a very long time. Whats this andSelf() method?

Comment: andSelf() is the same method as addBack(), just it is now deprecated

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To extend jquery methods:

```
$.fn.addBack = function (selector) {
    return this.add(selector == null ? this.prevObject : this.prevObject.filter(selector));
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Should I place this anywhere in particular? The bottom of the library maybe?

Comment: As soon as jquery library is loaded and before using this method

Comment: I think the "Or better" is worse, since andSelf doesn't filter by selector.

Comment: @sferrari you are correct. I edited post. Thx